# Why doesn't the keyring used by XFCE migrate to i3?

Tags: ubuntu, xfce, i3, xubuntu, gnome-keyring

I'm moving from Xubuntu XFCE to i3 and I have [this option checked in XFCE,](https://docs.xfce.org/xfce/xfce4-session/preferences)

> **Launch GNOME services on startup** Enable this option if you need the GNOME keyring daemon to be run on startup.

I can't figure out how to get the gnome-keyring to start with the same options under `i3` as it does under `xfce`? Tried many different things mentioned on the arch blog and elsewhere, I think it comes down to not understanding what that checkbox is doing. How do I migrate from Xubuntu with XFCE to i3 in such a fashion that the keyring options are preserved?

Currently when I move over to i3 basic things like Google Chrome's saved passwords disappear. I believe this is all a result of the keyring not working.

My `/etc/pam.d/lightdm` has,

```
session optional        pam_gnome_keyring.so auto_start
```

I believe this should work for all sessions. I've also tried numerous settings in `~/.xession`

From `ps`, I can see I have two interesting things running when I start an "Xubuntu Session"

```
/usr/bin/gnome-keyring-daemon --daemonize --login
/usr/bin/ssh-agent -D -a /run/user/1000/keyring/.ssh
```

If I start an `i3` session and then I start `chromium-browser` I get the following

> [14862:15007:1122/125338.085412:ERROR:token_service_table.cc(141)] Failed to decrypt token for service AccountId-$ACCOUNTIDNUMBER

Comment: Are you using something like `gnome-flashback` to run extra background services? Have you tried running `gnome-keyring-daemon` with an `exec` line in your i3 config?